# Regex for extracting build number from Copy artifacts plugin in Jenkins

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins build that copies an artifact from another build.

Using [description setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) I want to extract the build number from which I take the artifact.

The log file contains this line :

`Copied 1 artifact from "Mybuild" build number 569`

I need to use regex to extract only the integer `569` (can be any int). Also the `1` can be any int and `Mybuild` can be any string (but no spaces, one word). I can assume the words `Copied, artifact, from, build, number` are constant and always appear

I have tried to match a regex, but with no luck. Also tried some regex generator websites but no luck either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use

```
Copied (\d+) artifact from "([^"]+)" build number (\d+)
```

and then use the third group (or remove the parentheses around the first two captured tokens and use group number 1).

`\d` refers to any decimal digit, the `+` trailing it is a so-called *quantifier* that will try matching the previous token (the digit in this case) at least one times and as often as possible. `[^"]` is a character class containing any character that is not a double quote. This way we can make sure that we catch everything within the quotes (not strictly necessary here, but a good pattern to keep in mind). All the rest is just matched verbatim.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> 'Copied 1 artifact from "Mybuild" build number 569' -match 'Copied (\d+) artifact from "([^"]+)" build number (\d+)'
True
PS> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
3                              569
2                              Mybuild
1                              1
0                              Copied 1 artifact from "Mybuild" build number 569
```

Comment: If you want to learn more: http://regular-expressions.info is a very good resource, both for learning and for reference. It also explains quite well how the regex engine performs the matching for many constructs.